# How to do not allow whitespace before specific punctuation mark

Tags: c#, regex, string, text, punctuation

First of all I allow to the string only several punctuation marks, for example only dot and comma. It is does not shown here because no needed, just to know.

So if my string is:

```
string str = "hello,world,,,hello,,   world... world ,,,, world ...";
```

Then I do not allow to repeat this marks more the one time:

```
string filtr1 = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\.|,){1,}", m => m.Value.First().ToString());
```

Then if words are merged with punctuation mark between, I replace it with  white-space and keep mark at its place:

```
 string filtr2 = Regex.Replace(filtr1, @"[\,\.]", (m) => m + " ");
```

and also allow only one white-space between words:

```
  string result = Regex.Replace(filtr2, @"\s+", " ");
```

So now my result look like this:

```
  hello, world, hello, world. world , world .
```

But also I need here, if user type white-space before punctuation mark, **"hello , world"**  how do not allow white-space before specific symbols dot and comma to get this result **"hello, world"** for whole processed string result should be like this:

```
  hello, world, hello, world. world, world.
```

Comment: please elaborate , your question is not clear

Comment: @vivek nuna Hello, edited

Comment: Thanks for that Mickbt, but I think I understood it pretty well =). Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: string str2 = result.Replace(" ,", ","); done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize white-spaces first, then it will be easier to write the punctuation pattern:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ");
result = Regex.Replace(result, @" ?([.,]) ?(?:\1 ?)*", "$1 ");
```

Comment: Addison solution also should work, and seems like I'm doing something wrong there, but in my case this way works for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one expression if you get a little creative Mickbt.

Try searching for:

```
\s*(\.|,){1,}\s*
```

And replacing with: `\1`  (Note there is a **space** after the `\1`). [Example](https://regex101.com/r/NSV7AN/1).

In your case, the code would look like this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s*(\.|,){1,}\s*", "$1 ");
```

Good luck!

Comment: ,Hello, I tried this way, but not sure what I'm doing wrong here, result in this case, looks like this: `hello, world, hello, world. world  world` marks lost

Comment: it should  work, I do it same way as it shown in your example, but as I've said marks with space is lost in my case, seems like I'm doing something not really correct

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why it's not working for you, but I'm glad you got a solution.

Comment: @mickbt I wonder if it'd work if you used "$1 " as the replace statement? I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes it works, thank you for support, only question, how to mark both answers now... Anyway, both solutions works well